# Understanding how ldstr gets string literal

Tags: c#, cil

I want to analyse the IL code of a simple c# method:

```
public static string test()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

When I call `GetILAsByteArray` I'm getting the following bytes:

```
    [0] 0x00    byte
    [1] 0x72    byte
    [2] 0x01    byte
    [3] 0x00    byte
    [4] 0x00    byte
    [5] 0x70    byte
    [6] 0x0a    byte
    [7] 0x2b    byte
    [8] 0x00    byte
    [9] 0x06    byte
    [10]0x2a    byte
```

The second opcode is `ldstr`.

How I understood `ldstr` loads a string from metadata and pushes it on the stack.
([Description of ldstr from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr?view=net-5.0))

But how do I know which data is loaded from metadata? Tells me the following 0x01 that I have to take the data on index 1 from metadata or not? Or is ldstr followed by an int32? How should I interpret this bytes?

Comment: Everything you want to know about ldstr, and more, is available in the highly readable [Ecma-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type `hello` string in your code, compiler writes this string into `#US` stream of PE (exe/dll) file.

`#US` stream (user strings) - holds array of 16 bit Unicode strings and these strings are referenced directly by `ldstr`.

Let's take your example `72 01 00 00 70`, so in this case your string is located in offset `0x01` in `#US` stream.

The `#US` stream starts with a null byte and each following entry begins with a 7 bit encoded integer (represents the size in bytes of following entry).

More information can be found in [Ecma-355](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (*I I.24.2.4 #US and #Blob heaps* section)